# Getting error Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker' in IE11?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

While i am implementing a page with date control i am getting error :Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'.
       Textbox control with @class="datepicker":

```
 @Html.TextBox("ReleaseDate", String.Format("{0:d}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")), new { @class = "datepicker", type = "date" })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SZzf.png)
            enter code here

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("Hi");
            $('#ReleaseDate').datepicker();
        });
```

Comment: having below code:@Html.TextBox("ReleaseDate", String.Format("{0:d}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                                                      new { @class = "datepicker", type = "date" })


JS code:

$(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Hi");
        $('#ReleaseDate').datepicker();
        
    });

Comment: 1. Don't put code in comments, [edit] it into the question. 2. Check your console for other errors, are you missing a JS file perhaps? Does it work in Chrome?

Comment: Thanks David for the reply, yes i am getting error in console like i,e.Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker' i have added all the references which i can found while googling and Yes its working fine in chrome and edge but in IE i am not able to see the datepicker symbol in the textbox.

Comment: Did you even read my first comment? Try again...

Comment: Done David can you please look into it and help me out from this?

Comment: why did you put a datepicker css class on the html element if you are just going to reference by id?

Comment: is jquery-ui referenced in your page?

Comment: Yes Fran I have added references of jQuery.ui.core(1.8.9) to my page.

Comment: Is jQuery library added and loading properly? jQuery is needed before UI can be loaded.

Comment: jquery UI Core only? Take a look at http://jqueryui.com/download/ - you'll see if you just have the Core components, it does not include the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your jQuery UI version to a more current version.  I put in here the rendered HTML from your MVC so I could actually test this.  I tested with proper references, seems to work here: (tested Firefox and IE9 so should also work in IE11)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ReleaseDate').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha256-rByPlHULObEjJ6XQxW/flG2r+22R5dKiAoef+aXWfik=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-KM512VNnjElC30ehFwehXjx1YCHPiQkOPmqnrWtpccM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input class="datepicker" id="ReleaseDate" name="ReleaseDate" value="2018-02-12" type="date">
```

Note, if you mix and match new jQuery with older jQuery UI you might also run into issues.  For example jQuery 1.12.1 will not work with jQuery UI 1.8.13 so be aware of the mix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark.